# Symfony 5 - Best practice for injecting a Service class to a lot of my controllers?

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I have a lot of controllers that will need to use the Symfony `TranslatorInterface` for my alerts, flash messages etc.

**What is the best practice to inject a service in a lot of controllers without code repetition?**

My first thought was to create `BaseController` that will extend `AbstractController`, inject service there in the constructor and extend my current controller by the new `BaseController`.

#### Controllers/BaseController.php

```php
class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {

        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function trans(string $id, array $parameters = [], string $domain = null, string $locale = null): string
    {
        return $this->translator->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }
}
```

And from here in the controller that i will need a lot of translations i could:

#### Controllers/FooController.php

```php
class RegisterController extends BaseController //instead of AbstractController
{

    public function foo(): Response
    {
        
        $this->trans('test.message');

    }
    
    ...

}
```

Is this a good practice or should i traditionally inject `TranslatorInterface` inside parameters of my functions? Or maybe every translated controller should have constructor with it?

Comment: Your posted BaseController class should work and is a reasonable approach.  There are alternatives but discussing them is probably not a good fit for stackoverflow.  All opinion based with no right answer.  Might consider posting on the [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/) board which is more discussion oriented.  The real question is why you feel you need this.  Anytime you start to add core functionality is a bit of a red flag.  Have you considered using twig templates for your messages?  You get translation basically for free.

Comment: I think You're right. Adding core functionality just for the translations now looks silly to me. Twig might be very helpful, Thanks for giving me a new perspective :)